# react-native send image form data success with emu but error 422 on real device

Tags: android, ios, react-native, axios, http-status-code-422

so this is my problem :
my code just returning error 422 when send data from real devices, but doing good on emulator 
here is my form data code :

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('approval_store_code', this.state.selectedApotik.store_code);
data.append('delivery_method_id', 1);
data.append('recipe_document_images[]', {
  name: 'recipePhotos1',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  uri:
    Platform.OS === 'android'
      ? this.state.imageResep[0].uri
      : this.state.imageResep[0].uri.replace('file://', ''),
});
```

and this is the code when i send to server

```
      this.setState({spinner: true});
      const response = await REQ.createRecipe(this.state.accessToken, data);
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status == 200) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({spinner: false});
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SuccessFormPharmacy');
      } else {
        alert('error');
        this.setState({spinner: false});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({spinner: false});
      console.log('error send data : ', error);
      alert('error send Data!');
      return null;
    }
```

the axios code :

```
return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${API.BASE_URL}/v1/pharmacy/order`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: formData,
  });
```

the weird thing is, 
i have try using fetch instead of axios, didn't work for real device, but doing good on emulator
i have try save the image first to devices, it saved but didn't success sent to server

on real device returning **Error 422**